# Mermaid how to use inline code syntax highlighting

Tags: mermaid

Here is a Mermaid `flowchart` ([link](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNoljsFugzAMhl8l8hmhpAkpyaWa1sMuO3WnLZNqkbSgAalCEGWId19glixZv-1P3wKVtw403Fo_VTWGSD7OpiepXr4MXN_8RKIndXOv29SRXHznXlscBjI1sSbbNxnmPuLzdDXwDRl0LnTY2MRcNpCBWLvOGdBptBh-DJh-TXc4Rn-Z-wp0DKPLYHxYjO7c4D1gB_qG7ZBSZ5vow_u_5O6awQN70As8QR-kyvmRSVFSySmVKoMZNBM5Z0eqZMElE0Ie1gx-vU9QmquCK6UEpYyXZSHUTvvcl5vG-geJAVRU)):

```
flowchart TD
    A["`How to highlight SomeClass with code syntax?`"]
```

I am looking for it to display like this:

> How to highlight `SomeClass` with code syntax?

How can one get inline code highlighting syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the html `code` element along with some inline styling results in what you asked for:

```
flowchart TD
    A["How to highlight <code style='padding: 4px; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #E3E6E8'>SomeClass</code> with code syntax?"]
```

PS: The backticks you wrapped the whole string in have to be removed in order for this to work.